# zendesk/zoplim live chat body empty

Tags: magento, zendesk, zopim

I am integrate *Zopim chat* from *Zendesk* - [zopim.com](http://zopim.com) and in some cases get empty response.

Could it be some `cURL` parameters or something like this?

Please advise the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `?wmode=transparent` in iframe src value

> ```
> <iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank?wmode=transparent"
> ```
>
> return empty body

and

> ```
> <iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank"
> ```
>
> return zopim chat